# Is there any way to call a js function asyncronously from a java class extending org.apache.cordova.CordobaPlugin.java?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developping an Ionic app with a class extending org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin helping in background tasks. I need to notify an async event to my ionic side of the app. Can I register some kind of listener, callback function or other mechanism to call ionic/angular/javascript code from the java side?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can trigger webview from Native code.

For Android :

```
this.appView.loadUrl("javascript:yourmethodname());");
```

For iOS :

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"yourmethodname()"];
```

yourmethodname should be the javascript function you wish to call.

For your question, you can call a method with setTimeout which will run asynchronously.

**Approach 1:**

```
 this.appView.loadUrl("javascript:asyncMethod());");
```

In JS :

```
function asyncMethod(){
   setTimeout(methodtocall(),5000);
}
```

**Approach 2:**

or you can directly call the asyncmethod from Java

```
this.appView.loadUrl("javascript:setTimeout(methodtocall(),5000))");
```

It is better to use approach 1 as you can reuse it later in your js function too.